# Cannot parse xml from Yahoo! Fantasy Sports with c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, yahoo-api

I did some searching around the web and could not find the cause of my problem so I apologize if that has already been asked in another form I just did not understand.

My problem is that I am trying to parse the XML retrieved from Yahoo! Fantasy Sports but nothing seems to be working.

I have converted the XML I received (using a GET request with my credentials) into a string. Here it is for evaluation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <fantasy_content xml:lang="en-US" yahoo:uri="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/game/223/players"     xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" time="5489.1560077667ms" copyright="Data provided by Yahoo! and STATS, LLC" refresh_rate="60"     xmlns="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/base.rng">
- <game>
  <game_key>223</game_key> 
  <game_id>223</game_id> 
  <name>Football PLUS</name> 
  <code>pnfl</code> 
  <type>full</type> 
  <url>http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f2</url> 
  <season>2009</season> 
- <players count="25">
- <player>
  <player_key>223.p.8261</player_key> 
  <player_id>8261</player_id> 
- <name>
  <full>Adrian Peterson</full> 
  <first>Adrian</first> 
  <last>Peterson</last> 
  <ascii_first>Adrian</ascii_first> 
  <ascii_last>Peterson</ascii_last> 
  </name>
  <editorial_player_key>nfl.p.8261</editorial_player_key> 
  <editorial_team_key>nfl.t.16</editorial_team_key> 
  <editorial_team_full_name>Minnesota Vikings</editorial_team_full_name> 
  <editorial_team_abbr>Min</editorial_team_abbr> 
- <bye_weeks>
  <week>9</week> 
  </bye_weeks>
  <uniform_number>28</uniform_number> 
  <display_position>RB</display_position> 
- <headshot>
<url>http://l.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/7gLeB7TR77HalMeJv.iDVA--/YXBwaWQ9eXZpZGVvO2NoPTg2MDtjcj0xO2N3PTY1OTtkeD0xO2R5PTE7Zmk9dWxjcm9wO2g9NjA7cT0xMDA7dz00Ng--/http://l.yimg.com/j/assets/i/us/sp/v/nfl/players_l/20120913/8261.jpg</url> 
  <size>small</size> 
  </headshot>
  <image_url>http://l.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/7gLeB7TR77HalMeJv.iDVA--/YXBwaWQ9eXZpZGVvO2NoPTg2MDtjcj0xO2N3PTY1OTtkeD0xO2R5PTE7Zmk9dWxjcm9wO2g9NjA7cT0xMDA7dz00Ng--/http://l.yimg.com/j/assets/i/us/sp/v/nfl/players_l/20120913/8261.jpg</image_url> 
  <is_undroppable>1</is_undroppable> 
  <position_type>O</position_type> 
- <eligible_positions>
  <position>RB</position> 
  </eligible_positions>
  <has_player_notes>1</has_player_notes> 
  </player>
- <player>
  </players>
  </game>
  </fantasy_content>
```

The two methods I have tried are these (PLEASE NOTE: "xmlContent" is the string that contains the XML listed above):

```
1.)
XDocument chicken = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
var menus = from menu in chicken.Descendants("name")
select new
{
ID = menu.Element("name").Value,
};
```

and

```
2.)
byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlContent);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(ms);

foreach (XmlNode row in doc).SelectNodes("//fantasy_content"))
{}
```

Basically, I get no results enumerated. I have a feeling I am missing some key steps here though. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

**UPDATE:**

As per the awesome suggestions I received, I tried three more things. Since it is not working still, I did not listen very well. :) Actually, that is semi-accurate, please bear with my newbie attempt at working with XML here as I really am thankful for the responses. Here is how I am screwing up the great suggestions, can you offer another tip on what I missed? Thank you all again.

As per Jon Skeet's suggestion (this yields no results for me):

```
1.) XNamespace ns = "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/base.rng";
XDocument chicken = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
var menus = from menu in chicken.Descendants(ns + "fantasy_content")
select new
{
ID = menu.Element("name").Value,
};
```

As per the second suggestion (this throws me an error):

```
2.) var result = XElement.Load(xmlContent).Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "name");
```

As per the combinations of suggesting I need to identify the namespace and Yahoo! guide at: http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-xml_cs.html

```
3.)     xmlContent = oauth.AcquirePublicData(rtUrl, "GET");

byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlContent);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(ms);

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("fantasy_content", "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/base.rng");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/name", ns);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
}
```

Comment: Those two approaches are doing completely different things - the second one doesn't even *mention* `name` elements.

Comment: Looks like Jon's got it covered, but for info, the documentation for this scenario is here - msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx. Example 2 includes namespaces.

Comment: @merv-jackson WHat actually ended up being your solution?  I am trying to figure out how to parse the exact same XML data and put it into a database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what's tripping you up:

```
xmlns="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/base.rng"
```

You're asking for elements in the unnamed namespace - but the elements default to the namespace shown above.

It's easy to fix that in LINQ to XML (and feasible but less simple in `XmlDocument`)

```
XNamespace ns = "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/base.rng";
var menus = chicken.Descendants(ns + "name")
                   ...
```

Note that in your original method you're actually looking for `name` elements *within* the `name` elements - that's not going to work, but the namespace part is probably enough to get you going.

EDIT: It's not clear why you're using an anonymous type at all, but if you really want all the `name` element values from the document as ID properties in anonymous type instances, just use:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/base.rng";
var menus = chicken.Descendants(ns + "name")
                   .Select(x => new { ID = x.Value });
```

Note that there's no need to use `Descendants(ns + "fantasy_content")` as that's just selecting the root element.

Comment: Knowing me. I am over complicated this here so please accept my apology for misunderstanding. Sometimes I feel like I will be a perpetual newbie when it comes to C#. Anyway, I tried two things and I am getting no results. Which means I likely did not follow your instructions properly. I am going to post my updates and see if you can identify my error.

Comment: @Pickle: edit what you've tried into the question, along with the results.

Comment: Okay, I think I updated the post with what is needed to see my error. Let me know though if I left anything out. I'm really trying to not bug anyone with this as it seems so simple yet I keep messing it up. So, thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: @PickleJuavez: You're not using the code that I provided you - in particular, you're still trying to find elements just called "name" in no particular namespace.

Comment: Okay. 1.) Wow, yea, I totally missed where you took out the "from menu in" part of the code and I am sorry about that. I'd bet you answer a lot of questions and nothing is more frustrating than offering solutions and having mis-care cause a person to say it did not work when they simply did not write it correctly. 2.) IT WORKED! You're awesome! THANK YOU THANK YOU!!! If you have a moment, would you mind elaborating on your observation of my misuse of using the "name element without a namespace. Ultimately, I would like to populate a database with this so I would love to hear your suggestions.

Comment: @PickleJuavez: Basically `xmnls=...` sets the *default* namespace for any descendants which don't explicitly specify one. So the `name` element actually has the namespace of `http://fantasysports...`

Answer (score 0):

Element name consists of two parts: xmlns(**namespace**) and **localname**. If xmlns is absent, name is equal to local name. So, you have to create name with namespace or ignore it

You can ignore namespace in your LINQ, just use `LocalName`

```
   var result = XElement.Load(@"C:\fantasy_content.xml")
        .Descendants()
        .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "name")
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I think I screwed up your code because I got an error. Mind you, that is not surprising as I think I am sometimes C# "challenged." Would you mind looking at my updated post to see where I may have gone wrong. I am getting an error. Thank you!

Comment: Change `Load` on `Parse`, I've used Load because I've saved your xml into file

Comment: Your answer has actually been right on as well. I want to make sure you get some credit for this too so is there someway I can move the "growth" of this question into another question, you answer it, and I make sure you get the check mark too?